# CSS background-position offset x pixels from position

Tags: css

I came across the `background-position` property in the **[W3C CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position)**, which says up to 4 values can be specified to create an offset.

Example taken from W3C site

```
background-position: left 10px top 15px;   /* 10px, 15px */
background-position: left      top     ;   /*  0px,  0px */
background-position:      10px     15px;   /* 10px, 15px */
background-position: left          15px;   /*  0px, 15px */
background-position:      10px top     ;   /* 10px,  0px */
background-position: left      top 15px;   /*  0px, 15px */
background-position: left 10px top     ;   /* 10px,  0px */
```

How well supported is this in the latest browsers? I have searched on here and online but the questions that I found where 2-3 years old so I'm looking for an up-to-date answer.

I know that I can add some extra pixels to the image, use a percentage value or JS but there are many cases where it would be better to simply use CSS if possible.

Comment: For support http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts and for more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size you will get the support from mdn as well

Comment: I checked caniuse.com but it doesn't go into detail about the four value syntax for `background-position`. I'll check out MDN, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MDN, the current browser compatibility is as follows:

```
Feature                 Basic support              Multiple backgrounds
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Chrome                  1.0                        1.0
Firefox (Gecko)         1.0 (1.7 or earlier)       3.6 (1.9.2)
Internet Explorer       4.0                        9.0
Opera                   3.5                        10.5
Safari                  1.0 (85)                   1.3 (312)



Feature                 Four-value syntax
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Chrome                  25
Firefox (Gecko)         13.0 (13.0)
Internet Explorer       9.0
Opera                   10.5
Safari                  Nightly WebKit bug 37514
```

**Reference:** [background-position | CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position#Browser_compatibility)

Other references:

- [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)
- [SitePoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position)